# Locking out a file in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, flow, power-automate

I have a Power Automate that updates the properties of a Document

The problem that I am having is, if a user say User A has the document open in the browser for editing, and the Power Automate is started after that by some other user say user B, all the fields updated by the Power Automate are lost when user A makes some changes to the file and saves it, after the PowerAutomate is completed

Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: I have the same issue with this as well. The properties of a document can't be updated when its open in the browser. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

When userA is editing the documents in browser, the flow will failed to update file property, file is locked in SharePoint:

[image]

Please provide more information about the flow.

Comment: Its a teams site and multiple people can edit the document at the same time. I think that's when this issue will occur since check out is not required